# Discord (among others) filling syslog. Is there a privacy preserving solution yet?

Tags: snap, log, syslog, apparmor

Discord is constantly spamming the system for a ptrace read that is being repeatedly denied by AppArmor/Snap. This happens for good reason as it is intended to find what games you might be playing. Unfortunately, even if you turn off the option to broadcast what you are playing, Discord still makes these requests. This problem has been around since 2018 with a number of posts across StackExchange, GitHub, and Canonical Snapcraft forums.

A "solution" that is repeatedly stated is to run

```
snap connect discord:system-observe
```

but this simply let's Discord actually see your processes: the privacy invasion that is not desired.

See

[syslog filling with this error message, discord?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244368/syslog-filling-with-this-error-message-discord)

[Disk space suddenly used up for no apparent reason in 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234854/disk-space-suddenly-used-up-for-no-apparent-reason-in-20-04/1234881#1234881)

https://github.com/snapcrafters/discord/issues/23

https://github.com/snapcrafters/discord/issues/43#issuecomment-524582590

https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/auto-connections-for-discord/2392/30

There was supposedly going to be a way to silence these things, but I have not been able to find that ability as being confirmed yet. **Does anyone know if it has been added?**

In one of the GitHub issue posts it is suggested that adding

```
deny capability sys_ptrace,
```

to `/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.discord.discord`

followed up by

```
sudo apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.discord.discord
```

would work, but it seems that it does not work anymore. If the last number of people to have tried it correctly followed instructions, it would appear this ceased to work mid-August 2023.

**Does anyone have a solution that doesn't compromise privacy?**

Now, I have found something that might be a "fix" at

[How to turn off all the AppArmor DENIED messages from snaps?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443609/how-to-turn-off-all-the-apparmor-denied-messages-from-snaps/1443610#1443610?newreg=c296353d6f0f447ba6ec9da0777cf47a)

where it is suggested that running

```
echo -n quiet_denied > /sys/module/apparmor/parameters/audit
```

will, until restart, will suppress denial warning for all apps. I have not tried done this.

There was also a  cautiously proposed Grub modification to retain it after restart, but **would an alternative to the Grub mod be adding the above BASH script line to *.bashrc* succeed in keeping the setting preserved at startup?**

**Lastly, is the above `quiet_denied` the thing that was supposedly going to be added to AppArmor or Snap (whichever the proposed change reference in the links is)? If it is, how could it be used to quiet just the denials to Discord?**